# Python - OGR: Transform coordinates from meter to decimal degrees

Tags: python, gdal, ogr, coordinate-system

I have a point in a shapefile. The shapefile is in a WGS_1984_Web_Mercator Projected Coordinate System. I want to get the coordinates of that point in decimal degrees with GDAL/OGR in Python.

I am able to get the coordinates in meters with the code below.

I tried to transform the shapefile from a Projected Coordinate System to a Geographic Coordinate System without success. I assume it is not possible to remove a Projected Coordinate System with OGR. Is that right?

What other ways are there within OGR/Python to get the coordinates in decimal degrees?

```
import ogr

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')

shp = driver.Open('testpoint.shp', 0)
lyr = shp.GetLayer()

feat = lyr.GetNextFeature()
geom = feat.GetGeometryRef()

x = geom.GetX() #Get X coordinates
y = geom.GetY() #Get Y cooridnates

print x,y
```

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with OGR to know if there's something out of the box, but you can get the WGS84 lat/long values from the Pseudo-Mercator XYs. Warning: there's quite a bit of math involved if you want to roll your own conversion.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. There is a short explanation here how to do the math: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/30437/15607  But I would rather do it without calculating the coordinates manually.

Comment: Looks like that link has the answer with `ogr2ogr`and `-s_srs EPSG:3857` with `-t_srs EPSG:4326`

Comment: Yeah, I saw that too. However I like to do it in Python and not in the command line. Do you know how to use ogr2ogr within Python?

Comment: You could make a system call with `os.system()`

Comment: I figured out how to do the reprojection in Python with OGR. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to get the coordinates in decimal degrees, the data needs to be reprojected to WGS84.

```
import ogr, osr

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')

shp = driver.Open('testpoint.shp', 0)
lyr = shp.GetLayer()

feat = lyr.GetNextFeature()
geom = feat.GetGeometryRef()

# Transform from Web Mercator to WGS84
sourceSR = lyr.GetSpatialRef()
targetSR = osr.SpatialReference()
targetSR.ImportFromEPSG(4326) # WGS84
coordTrans = osr.CoordinateTransformation(sourceSR,targetSR)
geom.Transform(coordTrans)

x = geom.GetX() 
y = geom.GetY() 

print x,y
```

Comment: using this code, i only get 0.0 from all coordinates, should this code convert X_Coord and Y_Coord fields of the shape file ?