# How to read geographic coordinates when the Shapefile has a projected spatial reference

Tags: python, coordinate-system, ogr

I have a polygon Shapefile and want to read the polygon's vertices using OGR and Python. The reference system of the file is projected. However, for further processing I need the geographic coordinates of the vertices.

This is my code:

```
import ogr
path_to_infile = '/path/to/shapefile.shp' 
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile') 
infile = driver.Open(path_to_infile) 
layer = infile.GetLayer()
for area in layer: 
    area_shape = area.GetGeometryRef() 
    area_polygon = area_shape.GetGeometryRef(0) 
    no_of_polygon_vertices = area_polygon.GetPointCount() 
    for vertex in xrange(no_of_polygon_vertices): 
        lon, lat, z = area_polygon.GetPoint(vertex)
```

Coordinates (lat & lon variables) will be read according to the spatial reference. In my case, projected coordinates are displayed. Is there a way to directly extract geographic coordinates in OGR?

I know that .prj files of projected reference systems also store information on the corresponding geographic coordinate system. In arcpy for instance, geographic coordinates of a Shapefile with projected spatial reference can be accessed using the GCS property of arcpy.Describe(dataset).spatialReference:

```
import arcpy
# accessing projected coordinates
spatial_ref = arcpy.Describe(dataset).spatialReference 

# accessing geographic coordinates
spatial_ref.GCS
```

When spatial_ref.GCS is defined, I get geographic point coordinates for a polygon's vertices.

Is there a similar property for OGR available? Reprojecting is not my first choice, as I'm working in a custom reference system.

Comment: no tme for a full answer, but this could help http://www.gdal.org/osr_tutorial.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get geographic coordinates from a Shapefile with projected spatial reference, the geometries need to be reprojected when working with OGR. I tried to avoid this at first, because I'm working in a custom spatial reference system and I'm not sure about the reprojection parameters. When I look at the reprojected data in a GIS, they seem to be accurate, though.

I added the following lines to the script:

```
sr = layer.GetSpatialRef() 
geogr_sr = sr.CloneGeogCS()
proj_to_geog = osr.CoordinateTransformation(sr, geogr_sr)
area_polygon.Transform(proj_to_geog)
```

The final code looks like this:

```
import ogr
path_to_infile = '/path/to/shapefile.shp' 
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile') 
infile = driver.Open(path_to_infile) 
layer = infile.GetLayer()
# get projected spatial reference
sr = layer.GetSpatialRef()
# get geographic spatial reference 
geogr_sr = sr.CloneGeogCS()
# define reprojection
proj_to_geog = osr.CoordinateTransformation(sr, geogr_sr)
for area in layer: 
    area_shape = area.GetGeometryRef() 
    area_polygon = area_shape.GetGeometryRef(0) 
    # transform coordinates
    area_polygon.Transform(proj_to_geog)
    no_of_polygon_vertices = area_polygon.GetPointCount() 
    for vertex in xrange(no_of_polygon_vertices): 
        lon, lat, z = area_polygon.GetPoint(vertex)
```

The differences in speed from the reprojection are neglectable in my opinion (< 0.01 sec on average with ~35000 vertices on an off-the-shelf laptop).

[This post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61303/python-ogr-transform-coordinates-from-meter-to-decimal-degrees/61311#61311) was very helpful to me.

Answer (score 2):

For you, what is the difference between geographic coordinates and projected coordinates ?

From [ESRI GeoNet: Projected Coordinate System vs. Geographic Coordinate System](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/23160):

- A Geographic Coordinate Systems is defined by a 3-D surface and is measured in latitude and longitude.
- A Projected Coordinate systems refers to data that is defined by a flat 2-D surface and can be measured in units of meters and feet.
- When displaying data that's using a geographic coordinate system, ArcMap uses a 'pseudo-Plate Carree' projection. Basically, it just treat the coordinate values as if they're linear and just display the data.

Therefore if your coordinates are lat & lon variables, you use a Geographic Coordinate System (sensu ESRI)

1) With osgeo.ogr and a shapefile with WGS84 projection (Geographic Coordinate System), the crs is found by:

```
from osgeo import ogr
infile = ogr.Open("aWGS84.shp")
layer = infile.GetLayer()
# crs
spatialRef = layer.GetSpatialRef()
spatialRef.ExportToWkt()
'GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_84",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]'
```

You can also use `spatialRef.ExportToPrettyWkt()`,`spatialRef.ExportToProj4()`,`spatialRef.ExportToUSGS()` and many other formats.

First feature of the shapefile

```
feature = layer.GetFeature(0)
feature.ExportToJson()
'{"geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[5.826429692987699, 50.63093772365397], [5.830982302422351, 50.62928355089628], [5.826407932565759, 50.6268451632606], [5.82334832264974, 50.62941225500874], [5.826429692987699, 50.63093772365397]]]}, "type": "Feature", "properties": {"id": null}, "id": 0}'
```

And the point coordinates of the Polygon (WGS84 in degrees)

```
import json
json.loads(feature.ExportToJson())['geometry']['coordinates']
[[[5.826429692987699, 50.63093772365397], [5.830982302422351, 50.62928355089628], [5.826407932565759, 50.6268451632606], [5.82334832264974, 50.62941225500874], [5.826429692987699, 50.63093772365397]]]
```

2) With the same shapefile in a projected coordinate system (in meters)

```
infile = ogr.Open("aproj.shp")
layer = infile.GetLayer()
feature = layer.GetFeature(0)
json.loads(feature.ExportToJson())['geometry']['coordinates']
[[[253122.92278611325, 147711.88454888575], [253448.57840302447, 147534.25421241205], [253130.3240500753, 147256.7068115687], [252908.28612947493, 147537.9548443528], [253122.92278611325, 147711.88454888575]]]
```

3) For the conversion between the two geometries, I need to reproject the shapefile (degrees to meters) with `osgeo.osr` or [Pyproj](https://github.com/jswhit/pyproj) (there are many examples in GIS SE).

4) Instead of using osgeo.ogr why don't use the more "Pythonic" [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html) (another Python wrapper of the OGR library)

```
import fiona
file = fiona.open("aWGS84.shp")
spatialRef = file.crs
spatialRef
{'init': u'epsg:4326'}
```

Fiona use Python dictionaries for all (GeoJson format), therefore the first feature is obtained by

```
file.next()
{'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[(5.826429692987699, 50.63093772365397), (5.830982302422351, 50.62928355089628), (5.826407932565759, 50.6268451632606), (5.82334832264974, 50.62941225500874), (5.826429692987699, 50.63093772365397)]]}, 'type': 'Feature', 'id': '0', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'id', None)])}
```

Comment: I already use .GetSpatialRef() in the script to get information on the spheroid. From this command, I get the metadata from the projection file (as you posted in your first code example). There is a PROJCS part and a GEOGCS part (same as with UTM zone .prj files). I just want to use the GEOGCS, not the PROJCS parameters for the determination of coordinates. Arcpy has a functionality for this purpose and I want to know how this operation has to be coded in OGR.