# Convert shapefile to geographic coordinates with og2ogr

Tags: shapefile, ogr2ogr

I'm trying to start plotting maps in python with matplotlib's basemap, but every shapefile I've tried to far seems to have coordinates in metres instead of lat/lon, so I get the following error from `readshapefile`:

`ValueError: shapefile must have lat/lon vertices  - it looks like this one has vertices in map projection coordinates.`

Here's output from `fiona` about the shapefile I'm using:

`shape = fiona.open('./data/ESRI/London_Ward.shp')
bounds = shape.bounds
print(shape.crs)`

: `{'proj': 'tmerc', 'lat_0': 49, 'lon_0': -2, 'k': 0.999601272, 'x_0': 400000, 'y_0': -100000, 'datum': 'OSGB36', 'units': 'm', 'no_defs': True}`

`print(bounds)`
: `(503568.2, 155850.8, 561957.5, 200933.9)`

`ogr2ogr` is the only conversion tool I've managed to install so far, is it possible to use it to make the necessary conversion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is. Use it like this from the command line (might be necessary to `cd` into the folder where ogr2ogr has been installed to):

```
ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:4326 -f "ESRI Shapefile" transformed.shp London_Ward.shp
```

If you want to run it from Python, you can use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to set up the command and run it from the script, e.g. like this:

```
import subprocess as sub

input = r'./data/ESRI/London_Ward.shp'
output = r'./data/ESRI/London_Ward_WGS84.shp'
cmd = 'ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:4326 -f "ESRI Shapefile" {0} {1}'.format(output, input)
p = sub.Popen(cmd, stdout=sub.PIPE, stderr=sub.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
if p.exitcode != 0:
    print stdout
    print stderr
```

Alternatively, pass all parts of the command as a list like this:

```
p = sub.Popen([ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:4326 -f "ESRI Shapefile", output, input], stdout=sub.PIPE, stderr=sub.PIPE)
```

In case you really want to stay within Python and don't use the command line, use the accepted answer from [Python - OGR: Transform coordinates from meter to decimal degrees](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61303/python-ogr-transform-coordinates-from-meter-to-decimal-degrees/61311)

Also have a look at the [Documentation](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html)

---

EDIT:
After working a bit more with `subprocess`, I would like to update the call to the following:

```
import subprocess as sub

input = r'./data/ESRI/London_Ward.shp'
output = r'./data/ESRI/London_Ward_WGS84.shp'
cmd = ['ogr2ogr', '-t_srs', 'EPSG:4326', '-f', '"ESRI Shapefile"', output, input]
sub.call(cmd)
```

`subprocess` seems to like lists better than pure string commands.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think it was mainly the command-line options for ogr2ogr I needed help with.  Is there any reason you picked `subprocess` over `os.system` for running it in python?

Comment: Not really... I was just trusting the answer from [Difference between subprocess.Popen and os.system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813238/difference-between-subprocess-popen-and-os-system#4813571)